# initWithFrame of a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have declared a property in my UIView like this:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *finishedLines;`

which I initialize using:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        //[self setFinishedLines:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

What will be the difference if I uncomment the `[self setFinishedLines..]`?

*Isn't it already initialized when I declare the property?*

I am getting varying results if I uncomment but I don't understand the logic.

Answer (score 3):

Properties in objective-c are not automatically initialized.

You will have to alloc and init it (or use new which is basically a shortcut to alloc and init) in your constructor.

```
   self.finishedLines = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it'll not get initialized itself. You'll need to initialized it whenever you require. If you're sure at the time of calling `initWithFrame:` method, you'll need then you should "uncomment" your code.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration of a property of this type does not allocate an object to it. It is just a pointer to the `NSMutableArray`. It can be used by other objects to set an `NSMutableArray` on your `UIView` object. But you may also need to declare one internally (which you can do in your init) if you need to be sure that one is always accessible.